# Are there performance advantages of 32 bit apps over 64 bit ones, on x86-64?

Tags: performance, x86, x86-64, 32bit-64bit

I know the advantages of 64 bit over 32 bit, but except for compatibility, are there any advantages of 32 bit applications over 64 bit ones that could make 32-bit application faster or otherwise more efficient?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In short, no. To be more accurate, it might theoretically be the case for some processors, but none that I'm aware of.

The only other difference that comes to my mind is that 32-bit instuctions are generally smaller (due to not having a REX prefix, at least), so you might save some space this way, but it probably doesn't outweight the benefits of x64. Considering that instructions unique to x64 also tend to have higher impact, i.e. manipulating more data at once, the code might even turn out to be more compact in x64. And, for the same reason, x32 is generally slower. So no, x32 doesn't have any real advantages over x64, other than compatibility.

Comment: If you have a lot of pointer-heavy data structures, like trees, the best case is an ILP32 ABI for x86-64 (32-bit pointers in 64-bit mode like [Linux's x32 ABI](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X32_ABI)), because the cache footprint of your data structures are smaller vs. a normal 64-bit ABI.  32-bit mode can be faster in that case than regular 64-bit code, despite having fewer registers and a legacy calling convention, as long as you don't need more than 4 GiB of address space.  For copying large amounts of data around, you use SIMD (SSE or AVX) in either mode, for 16 or 32 bytes per insn.

Comment: That said, most programs are faster in 64-bit mode, especially if they don't naively use 64-bit integers for things they don't need to.  Modern CPUs can handle the larger average instruction size of x86-64 machine-code fairly well.

Answer (score 5):

There's one big advantage: 32-bit applications use significantly less memory (precisely because pointers are smaller). Not everything is a pointer, e.g. strings and numbers don't change their size, so the effective difference is not 2x. I happen to know about JavaScript engines specifically, where the 64-bit version typically uses around 50% more memory for the same workload than the 32-bit version of the same engine.

V8 has recently addressed this by implementing "[pointer compression](https://v8.dev/blog/pointer-compression)" in its 64-bit version. In theory, any C/C++ app could do the same thing, but it's a big engineering effort.

That said, this generally isn't a reason not to move to 64-bit, as other benefits (more registers, more address space) typically outweigh this drawback. But it does mean that if you're targeting devices/machines with less than 4GiB memory anyway, you might want to stick with 32-bit builds, if memory consumption is a concern.

(Performance, in my experience, is a mixed bag: smaller code and smaller data mean better cache utilization on 32-bit; OTOH having more and wider registers on 64-bit can save instructions there. In rare extreme cases, a 64-bit app can process twice as much data in the same time; most of the time the difference will only be in the range 1-5%, and can go in either direction: *sometimes* a 32-bit build is indeed a little faster than a 64-bit build; it really depends on what the app is doing.)

Comment: actually 32-bit code often has more cache misses as per some benchmarks I saw, because there are more memory accesses required. 64-bit code has more registers so it doesn't need to spill to memory a lot

Answer (score 0):

For windows apps, 32 bit are viewed as "most portable" (easier to distribute) though that's becoming less of an issue.

For memory hogs like Ruby it seemed to me like it used 1/2 the RAM, so you could run more apps on boxes that were RAM limited.  Not to mention "all apps" use less RAM (kernel, etc.)

It also ran faster, since it traverses all its memory to do garbage collection, which fit in cache better, there was less overall RAM to traverse, looking for pointers, etc.  At the same time, 64-bit is less likely to find false positives when the GC was looking for pointers, so small win for 64-bit there.

If you're real brave, you can try the hybrid x32 ABI (32 bit pointers, 64-bit registers) https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/121424/linux-and-x32-abi-how-to-use which is meant to kind of get the best of both worlds.  I'm really not sure why it isn't considered more of a popular option, it seems like a nice win to me, trade-off being you can't have more than 2GB RAM.  My guess is most people aren't in a very RAM constrained environment, or that the win over just going straight "32 bit kernel" (which is well supported) isn't enough motivation?  In essence, most boxes have gobs of RAM so it's not as much of a priority?

Comment: IIUC the problem with x32 is that porting software to it is much more work than people initially hoped, and given that (1) the target audience, (2) the benefits over x86 or x64, and (3) the time window until most people will prefer x64 anyways due to its higher memory limits are all relatively small, it just wasn't worth it.

Comment: @jmrk: Most things can just be compiled for x32 with no additional work if they already compile safely for 32-bit mode; it's the need for people to have a 3rd set of libraries installed for just a usually-small perf benefit that's really the showstopper for adoption.  Only a few things like a JVM or JS implementation with a JIT engine would need special porting work.  x32 type sizes are the same as in 32-bit mode, with only `long long` being a 64-bit type.  Possibly some difference in struct layout rules, like alignof(long long) and alignof(double) are probably 8 instead of 32-bit mode's 4.

Comment: x32 user-space processes can use 4GiB of RAM each, not just 2.  Same as 32-bit processes under a 64-bit kernel.  (It's the kernel that determines how much total *physical* RAM a computer can take advantage of, and x32 is just a user-space ABI; the kernel itself would always be fully 64-bit.)

Comment: @PeterCordes: sure; people hoped that "most" things could just be compiled, but then the practical observation was that a surprisingly large number of packages do need (significant) adaptations. The fact that a third set of libraries is needed is sort of a consequence: hypothetically, one could have had pure-x32 systems, but that doesn't work out because there's too much software that doesn't "just work" when compiled to x32 (or is closed-source, so recompilation is not an option).